# Extend onStartCommand() from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement `LifecycleOwner` from a messaging service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` but I can't override the `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()` methods because they are final in `FirebaseMessagingService` (I need to override them to imitate the code in `LifecycleService`).

Does anyone know a work-around for this? I need to implement `LifecycleOwner` because I have to observe `LiveData` from the messaging service.

Comment: @pskink I have to override all the lifecycle methods, I already can do the `onCreate()` but I need to override the other ones as well. You can find details on what I have to do if you check the `LifecycleService` class as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @pskink I already explained what I want to achieve in my post, what is not clear about it? Why do you care about what `FirebaseMessagingService` and `LifecycleService` have in common? That is not relevant to my question.

Comment: why would you want to override both `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()`? it looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and that's why i asked what you actually wanted to achieve... but if you think its not important then you would need to wait for someone else answer

Comment: I already explained why I want to override all the callback methods, cause I want to imitate what the `LifecycleService` class does, if you check the code of that class you will see that it calls different methods from each callback.

Comment: "`I need to override them to imitate the code in LifecycleService"` - so you want simply call `ServiceLifecycleDispatcher` methods and not `"to  imitate the code in LifecycleService"` since you are not extending any `LifecycleService`, are you? for `LiveData` see [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#work_livedata) (notice a blue `Note` below the list) and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#merge_livedata)

Comment: Thanks for the links @pskink, I think we might have different understandings of the word "imitate" cause if I were able to extend `LifecycleService` I wouldn't need to imitate its behavior, and yes I have to call the dispatcher methods. I already knew about the `observeForever()` method and I'm using it in unit tests but I preferred not to use it in the app code cause it seems like a hacky way to observe `LiveData`, but I guess there might not be a better way of doing it for this case.

Comment: if you read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) you will see: `"If you think you need a Lifecycle object inside a ViewModel object, a transformation is probably a better solution."` - i think this is the same case - they are saying about observing `LiveData` in `ViewModel` and you are sating about observing them in `Service` which cannot neither extend `LifecycleService` nor use `ServiceLifecycleDispatcher`

Comment: btw you can always check how [observeForever](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.java#219) is implemented and write your own version of [private static final LifecycleOwner ALWAYS_ON](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/java/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.java#68)

Comment: btw #2 *"I think we might have different understandings of the word "imitate""* now i see the source my misunderstanding: when you were writing `"imitate"` i was reading `"initiate"` - i think i need to visit my optician next week...

Comment: haha now that makes sense @pskink, I thought I was maybe using the word wrong as English is not my first language :P, thanks for the help anyway! In the end I decided to not do async work on the service but I'll leave the question here in case anyone wants to answer it and it helps someone else.